How to create\open from UIViewController a popup in Xamarin.iOS?
I have ViewController : UIViewController  which included one Title + one Button.
If I tap this Button. Xamarin.iOS app has to open  popup like picture
How Can I implement it?
Will the popup be as UIViewController  as well?
